# signature comparison in python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I want to compare two signatures in python and OpenCV. Is there any method with which I can do signature comparison

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific method. What I would suggest you to do is to get a feature vector of every signature (image has to be processed though, binarized preferably). Then, when you have the feature vectors of every signature, you can compare them and compute distance of the two feature vectors using some distance measure (Levenshtein, Manhattan, cosine...)

To get a feature vector, you can use any of the following [SURF](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html#surf), [ORB](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_orb/py_orb.html#orb), [SIFT](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_sift_intro/py_sift_intro.html#sift-intro), [BRIEF](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_brief/py_brief.html#brief)